How to read others app's shared storage on Android 13+?
From android 13, we now need to access files that are outside of or app's sandbox using MediaStore or Safe Access Framework.
In my case I want to use files under '/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media', my issue is that there is a .nomedia files inside it, so MediaStore doesn't index files in this folder...
I'm not sure about SAF, if I prompt user once to give access (file picker) will I have persistent access ? If new files are added after the user action, will I also be able to view them ?
Are there any other alternatives ?
Thanks in advance ! :)
